# Group by margin

Tags: scala

I am having a sequence of Int numbers:

```
val numbers = Seq(5, 3, 4, 1)
```

I need to group them according to their difference. The difference has to be smaller or equal to a certain threshold, let it be 2 for this example. So the possible groups would be:

- (5, 3, 4) (1)
- (1, 3) (5, 4)

I don't really care which of these constellations of groups I'll get. Each element is allowed to be used once. I also need to remain the index, so prior grouping I would need a zipWithIndex.

Is there a clever way to do such grouping?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the group by difference?

Comment: I think you need to provide more details about what you need. Do you need to generate all possible groups, or just one is enough? As the problem is described, you could trivially just create groups of one element each.

Comment: @Eduardo But groups of 1 are no fun :(. (you are right)

Comment: I need to group by the absolute value of difference between two values. An element can only join a group of values if its difference to each memeber of the group is smaller than the threshold. If it joins a certain group, it can not join another groups. One group constellation is enough. Each element should at least try to join a group. (no groups of one element)

Comment: @kreide with your description it is still possible to trivially have a group for each element alone.

Comment: That is what I mean by "each element should try to join a group". You already gave the right answer down there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok then. Idea of the algorithm:

Take the next element in `numbers`. Check whether it belongs to a previously created group. If it does, add it to that group. If not, add a new group with the element.
I use `IndexedSeq` because i want indexing to be `O(1)`.

It is kinda long, but I can't think of something better at the moment. I hope I understood you correctly with your idea of "difference".

```
val numbers = Seq(5, 3, 4, 1)

def group(seq: Seq[Int], treshold: Int) = seq.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(IndexedSeq.empty[IndexedSeq[(Int,Int)]])((result, elem) =>  {
    (0 until result.size).find(
        i => result(i).forall(num => (num._1 - elem._1).abs <= treshold)).map(
            i => result.updated(i, result(i) :+ elem))
                .getOrElse(result :+ IndexedSeq(elem))
})

println(group(numbers, 2)) //result Vector(Vector((5,0), (3,1), (4,2)), Vector((1,3)))
```

**Edit** forgot you wanted to `zipWithIndex`

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Could you also tell me how to maintain the prior index information? In this example: result Vector(Vector((5, 0), (3, 1), (4, 2)) , Vector(1, 3)). Should I use zipWithIndex?

Comment: @kreide I updated it to use `zipWithIndex`. (5,0) means the number 5 had the index 0 before.

Comment: Have a +1 from me as well. I'm not sure mine should be the accepted answer, since you gave a perfectly fine implementation first.

Comment: @TravisBrown It is called the best answer (not the first acceptable) and that should be decided by the one who asked it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're working with indices of elements anyway, you may not care about working with indices of the groups as well, in which case Kigyo's answer is probably the right one.

One of the nice things about functional programming is that it can often free you from working with indices, though, so for the sake of completeness, here's an implementation using `span` that doesn't need to track the indices of groups (first for the simple form without element indices):

```
val numbers = Seq(5, 3, 4, 1)

numbers.foldLeft(List.empty[List[Int]]) {
  case (acc, x) => acc.span(_.exists(y => math.abs(x - y) > 2)) match {
    case (bad, picked :: rest) => (x :: picked) :: rest ::: bad
    case (bad, _) => List(x) :: bad
  }
}
```

If you haven't already `zipWithIndex`-ed `numbers`, you can also take care of that during the fold without too much extra fuss:

```
val numbers = Seq(5, 3, 4, 1)

numbers.foldLeft(List.empty[List[(Int, Int)]], 0) {
  case ((acc, i), x) => acc.span(_.exists(y => math.abs(x - y._1) > 2)) match {
    case (bad, picked :: rest) => (((x, i) :: picked) :: rest ::: bad, i + 1)
    case (bad, _) => (List((x, i)) :: bad, i + 1)
  }
}._1
```

This returns `List(List((1, 3)), List((4, 2), (3, 1), (5, 0)))` as expected, and saves you an iteration through the sequence with very little extra verbosity.

Comment: I guess I should consider thinking about using `span` more. Your answer feels cleaner than mine. +1